# Malfuctioning key for Š, Ď, Ň etc. on playonlinux-executed MS Office

Tags: 15.10, keyboard-layout, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and MS Office installed and executed via playonlinux (problems both on 2007 and 2010 as well).

Everything works OK, the only problem is that the key used mainly for czech punctuation (marked red below) is dead. It has not any changed function, it just does nothing.

[image]

**Why is that so? Is there any remedy?**

The problem does not occur in LibreOffice, Gedit and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with the accent marks on MS Office in PlayOnLinux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/767200/problem-with-the-accent-marks-on-ms-office-in-playonlinux)