# Problem with the accent marks on MS Office in PlayOnLinux

Tags: 16.04, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I have a issue with the accent marks on Word in Ubuntu 16.04. When I'm writing and I need the mark, Word doesn´t write it.

I tried to change iBus to none, but the vowels with mark are showed like this:
´a ´e ´i ´o ´u

Sorry for my english, but I need to fix it
Have a nice day/night

Comment: I can't post a proper answer because I don't have enough reputation. It is not enough to disable iBus, you have to remove it completely. To do that, simply remove the package `ibus-table`. Attention! Do not remove the package `ibus` itself, as that will remove Unity as well.

Answer (score 8):

I have solved it. There are two actions to apply:

1. Solves the problem when you launch the application and then open the file.

   - To do so, follow *ingasvist's* user instuctions: go to Playonlinux, select Office program (Word, Excel, ...), go to Configure (do not get confused by "Configure Wine"), go to the `Miscellaneous` tab, and in the `Command to exec before run` textbox, enter: `XMODIFIERS=""`. That solved it. Keep the keyboard entry method on IBus. Repeat for other office links.
2. Solves the problem when you want to open directly the file from your file browser.

   - Go to the files located at `~/.local/share/applications`. Use a text editor to modify Office launcher files and look for the line which begins like `Exec=...`. Modify this line by adding `env XMODIFIERS=""` to it. This is what mine looks like now:

     ```
     Exec= env XMODIFIERS="" /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2010" %F
     ```

I hope this helps!

Cheers!

PD: this answer is thanks to the contribution of *ingasvist* user, this [blog](http://zonaelementaryos.com/2015/07/22/instalar-microsoft-office-2010/), and this [faq website](https://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/linux/faq/Ubuntu/XenialXerus).

Answer (score 1):

Open playonlinux and select the Excel shortcut, then click configure. Go to the 'Miscellaneous' tab, and in the 'Command to exec befor run' textbox, enter: XMODIFIERS="".
That solved it in my situation. Keep the kbd entry method on IBus. 
Repeat for other office links.